# Is "des" in "dont les yeux roulaient des larmes" an indefinite article or "de" + "les"?

Tags: prépositions, verbes, articles

The question is on *roulaient des larmes* found in this sentence from Flaubert's L’Éducation sentimentale.

> L’enfant, dont les yeux roulaient des larmes, venait de s’éveiller.

**Question**

Which of the following is right?  If none of them, please let me know what's going on.

(a) *rouler* is a transitive verb, *des* is an article, and *larmes* (or *des larmes*) is a direct object.

(b) *rouler* is an intransitive verb, *des* is made of *de* and *les*, and *des larmes* is a complement modifying the verb.

(c) *des* is made of *de* and *les*, *rouler de* is a transitive verb, and *larmes* (or *les larmes*) is a direct object.

**Background**

In [this](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/rouler#) and [this](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/rouler) dictionary entries I found many other expressions similar to the one above.

In some of them *rouler* is clearly taking a direct object.  For example:

> rouler une cigarette
>   rouler les épaules
>   rouler les hanches
>   rouler les mécaniques

In another, *rouler* is clearly not taking a direct object.

> rouler du cul

Here I expect:  This expression can receive parsing per (b) or (c) but not (a), which is to say that *du* cannot be a partitive article because *cul* is the sort of thing you can count. *rouler du cul* involves exactly one *cul*. If *Tom roule du cul*, only his own *cul* can be involved. But if *Tom roule le cul* it could be his own or someone else's.

But the following expressions, having *des* in them, give me the same sort of trouble as does *des larmes*

> rouler des cigarettes
>   rouler des fesses
>   rouler des hanches
>   rouler des mécaniques

Of these, *rouler des cigarettes* is probably the same thing as *rouler une cigarette* except in the number of cigarettes being rolled.  But *des hanches* probably means *of the hips*. Assuming that each person has two *hanches* interpreting *des* as *some* would seem to me very odd. I'd want to ask, 'What do you mean you shook some hips, have you got more than two, were you shaking other people's too?' I think I should want to say either that I *shook the hips* or *shook of the hips*, not some indefinite number of hips. *des mécaniques* seems most like *des larmes* in that you have any number of *mécaniques* and I cannot try to rule out any of (a) through (c) based on semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a direct object. Tear are rolling, and not rolled, even in French.

For your other problem expressions:

> rouler des cigarettes

Here you are right, it means "to roll several cigarettes"

> rouler des fesses
>   rouler des hanches

Both these means you have a specific way of moving that makes your butt do a rolling movement. Here it is equivalent to "de les".

> rouler des mécaniques

Here "mécaniques" is a slang for "muscles", so it means "to flex". It is the same construction as "rouler des hanches".

Comment: "de les", the edit should makes it clear.

Answer (score 2):

The sense seems to be:

> Les yeux de l'enfant roulent des larmes.

So it's a direct object, like 'rouler une cigarette'.

For 'rouler du cul' (same for 'des hanches'), the meaning is 'from the ass', not 'some ass'. Like 'puer du cul', 'grossir du cul', 'saigner du cul'. I think, that's how I've always understood it. Now that I'm trying to explain it, I'm doubting...